# Apache rewriting eats one level of escaping (%23)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to use fancy URLs for a tag filter on my website. The URLs should look like http://example.com/source/+tag1+tag2. This should filter for all items tagged with tag1 and tag2. I came up with the following rewrite rule for that, which I have saved to the root directory of the site:

```
RewriteRule ^([^+]+)(\+.+)$ $1?tags=$2 [L]
```

This works fine for all normal tag names, but it fails for the tag name "c#". I know that the hash character is not sent to the server, so the tag name is url-encoded and the link in the HTML page is like this: `./+c%23` But the target page will only see the "c" in its tags parameter, the rest and anything after the "#" is not there anymore.

I have enabled Apache's rewrite logging and saw that it already logs the incoming URL request like `…/+c#`. This made me think that another level of escaping could be required. So I tried with %2523 which actually passed the rewriting successfully and the whole string "c#" turned up in my page.

But then again, when I access the page with its internal URL like `./?tags=c%23`, it already works, too. So why is Apache eating up one level of escaping? Is there a hidden rewrite flag I can use to avoid that? Do I need to use public URLs that are double-encoded for my fancy URLs to work? Or will it be too messy and I should instead just rename my tag to "csharp"?

Comment: I think you need http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b (so `[L,B]`)

Comment: Good point, but it doesn't seem to work. The rewrite log says: rewrite 'de/source/+c#' -> 'de%2fsource%2f?tags=%2bc%23' And then the resulting URL cannot be found. It's escaping way too much. Only the "#" should be re-escaped, not all other important parts of the URL path.

Comment: Solved. I needed to create another .htaccess file right in the directory of the page to avoid all "/" escaping. Could you please add your comment as answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: Could you also add your solution, so others can learn from it too? Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the [B flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) (so use [L,B])

Comment: That's indeed the option I was looking for. But it will escape the entire URL string in the process of rewriting, including path delimiters (/) and the plus character (+) I use for tag name separation. Since a file with %2F in it (escaped for /) did not exist, I needed to move that part of the .htaccess file right into the directory where the target page is located. Then I could use my above rewrite rule, only with the [L,B] prefix.